# Use Default Value checkbox and label is showing for All Store Views also in Product Form(Product Edit) Admin Panel

Tags: custom, admin-panel, product-grid, product-description, product-edit-page

Here I am working on to display newly added Description field on Product Edit form under content Tab and default one has hided using css.

An issue is in below code that **Use Default Value** checkbox and label is showing for **All Store Views** also in Product Form but should be hidden. I am trying to hide it for **All Store Views** and it's working fine for other stores.

Here I followed this link: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/customize-modifier-class.html

*Please check below code:*

> Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\product_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content">
        <field name="description" template="ui/form/field" sortOrder="50" formElement="wysiwyg">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="pagebuilder_button" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Description</label>
                <dataScope>description</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <wysiwyg>
                    <settings>
                        <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                    </settings>
                </wysiwyg>
            </formElements>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

> Vendor\Module\etc\adminhtml\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="advancedInventory" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Description</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

> Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Description.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;

class Description extends AbstractModifier
{
    /**
    * Add Use Default Value checkbox to New added Description Field in Product Form 
    * @param array $meta
    *
    * @return array
    */
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta): array
    {
        $meta['content']['children']['description']['arguments']['data']['config']['service']['template'] = 'ui/form/element/helper/service';
        $meta['content']['children']['description']['arguments']['data']['config']['disabled'] = 1;
        return $meta;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }
}
```

After writing this code, achieved output. Please check screenshot, it is visible for All Store Views as well but It should be hidden :
[image]

> If any Idea, please share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added condition for All Store Views, Please check below answer.

> Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Description.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Attribute\ScopeOverriddenValue;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;

class Description extends AbstractModifier
{

    protected $_storeManager;

    private $scopeOverriddenValue;

    protected $locator;

    const ALL_STORE_VIEWS = "Admin";
    
   
    public function __construct(      
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        ScopeOverriddenValue $scopeOverriddenValue,
        LocatorInterface $locator
    )
    {    
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->scopeOverriddenValue = $scopeOverriddenValue;
        $this->locator = $locator;
    }

    
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta): array
    {
        $storeName = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getName();

        if ($storeName !== self::ALL_STORE_VIEWS) {
            $meta['content']['children']['description']['arguments']['data']['config']['service']['template'] = 'ui/form/element/helper/service';
            $meta['content']['children']['description']['arguments']['data']['config']['disabled'] = !$this->scopeOverriddenValue->containsValue(
                \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface::class,
                $this->locator->getProduct(),
                'product_custom_attribute_code',
                $this->locator->getStore()->getId()
            );
        }

        return $meta;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: @all, Here i am facing issue for the "Default Store View" scope: when I uncheck the "Use default value" checkbox on the description field, then save my change, the contents of the description field shows the changes I made but the checkbox is checked again. The product page does show my changes, so it is functioning better than before but checkbox is checked again is confusing.